# "Gboard Recording, therefore WhatsApp Temporarily unable to record." error message

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, gboard, microphone, realme

I have a Realme phone. The following error message shows up every time I make a WhatsApp call, and I can't hear the caller

> GboardRecording, therefore WhatsAppTemporarily unable to record.

Is there any way to stop Gboard recording? How to fix it?

Comment: Gboard should not be recording unless you tell it to, but if it says that it's recording i would suggest you go into gboards app info and force stop the app or restart your phone

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings> applications> apps> Gboard> permissions> deny microphone access